# facing error while creating custom widget in Dojo, could not identify the reason for the error

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx

I have created a custom widget for showing tooltip while u click on a icon. When i add this template of other widget I am getting " dojo/parser.js:900 dojo/parser::parse() error Error: Unable to resolve constructor for: 'CustomPopup' " following error. I am attaching my code here. CustomPopup is the widget for showing tooltip. (both html and js are in same directory)

CustomPopup.html

```
  <span id="${id}"   data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: myClickHandler, mouseout: myMouseOut"></span>
```

CustomPopup.js

```
define([       
        'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
        'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',  
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dojo/on',
        'dijit/registry',
        'dijit/TooltipDialog',
        'dijit/popup',
        'dojo/mouse',
        'dojo/dom',
        'dijit/_AttachMixin',
        'dojo/text!./CustomPopup.html',
        'dojo/parser'

        ],function(  _WidgetBase,_TemplatedMixin,_WidgetsInTemplateMixin, declare,on,registry,TooltipDialog,popup,mouse,dom,_AttachMixin,htmlTemplate,
                    parser)
{
return declare([_WidgetBase,_TemplatedMixin,_WidgetsInTemplateMixin,TooltipDialog],{


           templateString    : htmlTemplate,


           myClickHandler: function(e){
                            console.log('hiiii');
                           },
           myMouseOut: function(){
                           console.log('bhhhh');
                           },

_toolTipDialog : null    

            });
        });
```

I am adding this widget to another widget to get tooltip, that HTMLtemplate is

somewidget:

```
<div id="mainId" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" data-dojo-props='diaplayedValue:"10"' id="jet" style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" data-dojo-props='displayedValue:"20"' id="jet1" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div  data-dojo-type="CustomPopup" id="klm"></div>

</div>
```

I am getting the below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2twH.png)

more info[image]

so ,could someone pls help to fix my error.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use id for dojo widgets.
Use data-dojo-attach-point instead